# How to Search in List<string>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<string>` that has some items look like this in my View:

```
1S61A9MAT1DKV5N74925,
1S61A9MAT1DKV5X49329,
1S61A9MAT1DKV5X49857
```

and i want search efter this items , but to be honest i don't know what should i tell my Controller,when its comes `List<string>` i tried something like this in my controller`s.SerialNoInvoiceOrdrelineDeliveryCloses.Contains(searchString)` but its not worked , i mean when i search for this item `1S61A9MAT1DKV5N74925` it can pass the value to controller ,but it cant find any results for that item i searched. and as you see in my
 Contorller i have some Property which is string and there is one which is `List<string>` ' **SerialNoInvoiceOrdrelineDeliveryCloses** '

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult test(string searchString) {

        string EmailID = Session["Email"].ToString();

        var v = (from cbr in db.Contact_Business_Relation
                 join c in db.Contact on cbr.Contact_No_ equals c.Company_No_
                 join sih in db.Sales_Invoice_Line on sa.No_ equals sih.Document_No_
                 where c.E_Mail == EmailID

                 select new ClosedOrders
                 {
                     OrderNumber = sa.Order_No_,
                     Fakturanummer = sih.Document_No_,
                     varnummer = sih.No_,

                     //List<string>
                     SerialNoInvoiceOrdrelineDeliveryCloses = db.Item_Ledger_Entry
                     .Where(s => s.Item_No_ == sih.No_)
                     .Select(s => s.Serial_No_)
                     .ToList()
                 });

        if (searchString !=null)
        {
            v = v.Where(s => s.OrderNumber.Contains(searchString) 
                        || s.Fakturanummer.Contains(searchString)
                        || s.varnummer.Contains(searchString) 
                        || s.SerialNoInvoiceOrdrelineDeliveryCloses.Contains(searchString) 
                      );
        }
        return View(v);
    }
```

ViewModel :

```
public class ClosedOrders
{
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string Fakturanummer { get; set; }
    public List<string> SerialNoInvoiceOrdrelineDeliveryCloses { get; set; }
    public string varnummer { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("test", "Account", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
        Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
}

//Loop Model
        foreach (var item in Model)
        { 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.Fakturanummer
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.OrderNumber
                </td>
                <td> @item.varnummer</td>
                <td>
                    @String.Join(", ", item.SerialNoInvoiceOrdrelineDeliveryCloses)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

Comment: You should not pass `IQueryable` to viewer. I suggest you put a `.ToList()` at the end of your queries.

Comment: @roozbehS you are right ,dat was the cause all the problems IQueryable , when i tried pass IQueryable to view and i changed .ToList() everything get it work :) Merci koliii Roozbeh :) if you like postet as anwser and i will mark as right anwser

Comment: Glad I could help. Added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are sending `v` as `IQueryable<ClosedOrders>` to the view. It is a bad practice to pass an `IQueryable` to a view and have it run the query. First because you are sending unresolved query to the end point, Second you need to add related references to your view code. I suggest you add `.ToList()` at the end of your query and send the list to the view:

```
var v = (from cbr in db.Contact_Business_Relation
                 join c in db.Contact on cbr.Contact_No_ equals c.Company_No_
                 join sih in db.Sales_Invoice_Line on sa.No_ equals sih.Document_No_
                 where c.E_Mail == EmailID

                 select new ClosedOrders
                 {
                     OrderNumber = sa.Order_No_,
                     Fakturanummer = sih.Document_No_,
                     varnummer = sih.No_,

                     //List<string>
                     SerialNoInvoiceOrdrelineDeliveryCloses = db.Item_Ledger_Entry
                     .Where(s => s.Item_No_ == sih.No_)
                     .Select(s => s.Serial_No_)
                     .ToList()
                 }).ToList();
```

and:

```
v = v.Where(s => s.OrderNumber.Contains(searchString) 
                        || s.Fakturanummer.Contains(searchString)
                        || s.varnummer.Contains(searchString) 
                        || s.SerialNoInvoiceOrdrelineDeliveryCloses.Contains(searchString) 
                      ).ToList();
```